# Stripping Body of Outlook Email into Memo field

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

Has anyone ever been able to strip the body out of an Outlook.msg file into a Memo field?  I am seriously stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msgfile=getfile('msg')
o = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
emailmsg = o.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
memofiledvariable = emailmsg.body
```

The only caveat is you will need to give foxpro security access in Outlook. There are ways around this using Outlook Redemption or an automated clicking program.

Comment: Rich - I have a folder on c:\ that has emails saved as .MSG files.  How would I incorprate your code to put the body of the email into the cmemails.mbody field?  
 USE CMCONTROL IN 0
 USE CMEMAILS IN 0
 local array MyFiles[1,5]
  nFilesFound = ADIR( MyFiles, ALLTRIM(cmcontrol.cpath) + '*.*')
  xx = 0
 for i = 1 to nFilesFound
  xx = xx + 1
  insert into cmemails (cprimary, csubject, ddate, dtime, cattribs) values (generateGuid(26), MyFiles[ i, 1], MyFiles[ i, 3], MyFiles[ i, 4], MyFiles[ i, 5] )
 endfor
 USE IN SELECT('CMEMAILS')
 USE IN SELECT('CMCONTROL')

Comment: DO I need to ask this as a separate question?

Comment: in for loop, so the above code.  change insert statement to include body.  Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 1 to nFilesFound xx = xx + 1 
    do above code here as you got it working in test
    insert into cmemails (cprimary, csubject, ddate, dtime, cattribs,mbody) values (generateGuid(26), MyFiles[ i, 1], MyFiles[ i, 3], MyFiles[ i, 4], MyFiles[ i, 5] ,memofieldvariable) 
endfor
```